# For a procedure that returns Task what does it mean to return nothing?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Consider a method Foo() declared to return a Task object

```
public async Task Foo()
{
    try
    {
       // some preliminary code that can throw exceptions
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      // do something about the error but we do not want
      // to propogate it up.
      return;
    }
    await SomeOtherMethodThatReturnsTask();
}
```

The C# compiler does not complain about the naked "return" at all even though it is not returning a "Task" object.   Why is that allowed?  What is happening underneath here?   Is C# fabricating a Task object to return here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `async` keyword on your method signature changes the compilation of your method into a kind of state machine that causes it to return a `Task` that gets completed when your method's code completes. The mere presence of that keyword means that your method's code is translated into much more complicated compiled code.

If you're at all familiar with the `yield return` keyword, it's a similar principle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for `async` methods compiler automatically generates `Task` result. There is no way to manually return `Task` from `async` method.

Note that in your sample if "preliminary code" does not have `await` you don't need to mark method `async` and can return task yourself:

```
public Task Foo()
{

    // some synchronous code (no await)
    ...
    if (someCondition)
    { 
       return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
    return SomeOtherMethodThatReturnsTask();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use Task if no meaningful value is returned when the method is completed.That is, a call to the method returns a Task, but when the Task is completed, any await expression that's awaiting the Task evaluates to void.

[async (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx)